# How to write custom JSON Decoder strategy for Double type in Swift

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

Is there any way to write a custom decoder strategy for the Double type, just like we can for the Date type using `dateDecodingStrategy`?

The problem is that sometimes I get the JSON value as a String and sometimes as a Number.

I know I could write a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)` for each struct that has this problem, but there are a lot of them, I was hoping to do this only in one place and keep using `Double` as the fields' type.

Comment: Impossible. Ideally wrap `Double` into a custom type with a custom decoder and use it everywhere instead of `Double`.

Comment: I thought about it, but we can't even subclass Double, right? It would have to be a wrapper with a double value. But thanks anyway

Comment: Wrapper is not a bad thing. I often have multiple wrappers for `Double` in my project and not only because of encoding, e.g. `Money`, `InterestRate` etc. A wrapper allows you to add helper methods that are specific for a value.

Comment: I'm feeling too lazy to write this up properly, but the best approach I've seen is property wrappers. https://gist.github.com/AliSoftware/eff27d01bf0b4b74c0239001fd0c4f50  For the full discussion see Oliver Halligon's excellent FrenchKit talk: https://youtu.be/cw95S8gwkEU

Comment: (If you're stuck; ping me and I'll write it up as a real answer; I just didn't want to leave you without something.)